# How can I connect VS Code source control with a GitHub profile to directly push, commit, and sync changes and even push the repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-commit, source-control-explorer

How can I connect VS Code source control with a GitHub profile to directly push, commit, and sync changes and even push the repository?

Committing and syncing with the git repo is easy if we open the proper repo directory to push.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just open a folder managed by git. It is git that is connected to github. VSCode just understands git so it works automaticaly without needing you to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code should "just work" (see [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview)) as long as you've configure your git remotes. You can do that via commandline with the `git remote` commands. If you want to add a remote, use `git remote add <name> <URL>`. If you want to modify the url of an existing remote, use `git remote set-url <name> <newurl>`.

For docs, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote and https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes.

I don't know what you mean by "publish" (in contrast to "push"). If you mean publishing a GitHub pages site, that should work automatically when you push changes to the branch that your GitHub pages site is configured to track.

Answer (score -1):

first copy your repo url then go to source panel click on initialize repository
after that click on three dots placed on upper side and than click pull,push
option placed in lower column then click on push to and click on add remote and
past the copied url and add name and press enter. your github profile is linked